# Iframe in firefox loads css before js and breaks styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, iframe

A site with an *iframe* loads ok in **Chrome**, but when it comes into **Firefox**, it uses javascript to replace the *select/option* with *ul/li*, so when the replacement is done, the css is already loaded and the page doesn't show the styling properly (transparent *div* that contains the *ul/li/a* array).

If you right-click the *iframe* and go to **ThisFrame** dialog and click **ReloadFrame**, you will be able to see the proper style now.
If you open the *iframe* in a new window the styling works ok.

I did some testing myself and checked some info on bugs that **Firefox** may have but I just found this: https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/970521

And a mention about *http/https* calls, but this appear to not be the case. I know there's also a problem when the *iframe* is hidden and then it's shown, but I'm not sure this is happening because in the other documented cases, the *iframe* shows nothing at all ([Iframes in firefox not updating when hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452625/iframes-in-firefox-not-updating-when-hidden)).

Any help, whether it be which is the real problem or which could be the solution would be really appreciated.

The **site** is: http://www.odenresor.se/boka-direkt/nyahyrbil/

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: If your Iframe calls for ad tracking your antivirus program might be blocking them.  Avast does that with Web Rep. Green A near top of screen.  It may not be installed  in other browsers.

Comment: Cannot add the code here @Teemu, that's why I added the links to the pages. I have no access to the "main" code.